# how to compare datamodel Dynamics CRM in DTAP

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

we are currently using the [DTAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production) (Development, Testing, Acceptance and Production) model in our Dynamics CRM 2011 environment. In the ideal situation we use solutions to be installed on each environment, however it occurs that manual adaptions are also performed.

To guard the data model, I want to create a "base line" data model which we can use to validate against after each deployment. There are managed 3rd party solutions and unmanned solutions in the system.

I have already used the solution packager from the CRM SDK to extract the solutions and then compare the content using WinMerge/Windiff (plain xml compare). I also used http://crmcustomcompare.codeplex.com, but this is not satisfying and using the metadata browser is very work intensive.

I wonder if there are other ways to guard the data model in the DTAP street of CRM.

Comment: What does"guard the data model in the DTAP street of CRM" mean?  Googling DTAP returns a vaccine...

Comment: @Daryl I've edited the question for the poster to provide info on DTAP (not the vaccine, ha!)

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about are the entities and attributes, the early bound generator combined with a diff tool does a great job of showing where things have changed.

Comment: Are you stating that I should generate classes using the early bound generator on each environment and then perform a compare of the source files ?

Comment: @Dre If all you want to know is what entities / attributes / option sets / option set values have been added or removed, that's all you need to do.